# Oracle SQL: Using intervals to specify ranges of hours

Tags: sql, oracle

I have power meter data stored in table MeterData:

```
    create table MeterData (
    MeterID VARCHAR2(10), DownloadCycle VARCHAR2(6), DateHour Date,
    KWH Number(22,6), KW Number(22,6), KVA Number(22,6), KVAR Number(22,6),
    CONSTRAINT UniqueDownload UNIQUE(MeterID, DownloadCycle, DateHour))
```

The data looks like this:

| MeterID | DownloadCycle | DateHour | KWH | KW | KVA | KVAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2319927 | 202206 | 13/06/2022 00:00 | 0.138 | 0.552 | 0.552 | 0 |
| 2500350 | 202206 | 13/06/2022 00:15 | 0.612 | 2.448 | 2.916 | 1.584 |
| 2500351 | 202206 | 13/06/2022 01:30 | 0.8 | 3.2 | 3.2358 | 0.48 |
| 2500352 | 202206 | 13/06/2022 04:00 | 0.288 | 1.152 | 1.44 | 0.864 |
| 2500353 | 202206 | 13/06/2022 05:30 | 0.90808 | 3.63232 | 4.32456 | 0 |
| 2500396 | 202206 | 13/06/2022 12:00 | 68.09 | 272.36 | 277.101157 | 51.04 |
| 2500446 | 202206 | 13/06/2022 18:15 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2500453 | 202206 | 13/06/2022 21:00 | 2.772 | 11.088 | 11.088 | 0 |
| 2500472 | 202206 | 13/06/2022 23:30 | 64.8 | 259.2 | 305.788256 | 162.24 |
| 2500490 | 202206 | 14/06/2022 00:30 | 2.4 | 9.6 | 9.6 | 0 |
| 2501352 | 202206 | 14/06/2022 01:45 | 11.64 | 46.56 | 46.56 | 0 |
| 5187222 | 202206 | 14/06/2022 06:30 | 1.452 | 5.808 | 7.392 | 0 |
| 5284288 | 202206 | 14/06/2022 11:00 | 66.792 | 267.168 | 267.447334 | 149.336 |
| 5516997 | 202206 | 14/06/2022 18:30 | 0.384 | 1.536 | 8.112 | 0 |

I need to assign every record in table MeterData to a range of hours stored in table HourlyBlocks, in which I'm using intervals as the starting and ending hours:

```
    create table HourlyBlocks (
    HourlyBlock VARCHAR2(6) UNIQUE, BlockStart INTERVAL DAY(1) TO SECOND(0),
    BlockEnd INTERVAL DAY(1) TO SECOND(0));
    insert into HourlyBlocks values (
    'Rest', interval '0 05:00:00' day to second, interval '0 18:00:00' day to second);
    insert into HourlyBlocks values (
    'Peak', interval '0 18:00:00' day to second, interval '0 23:00:00' day to second);
    insert into HourlyBlocks values (
    'Valley', interval '0 23:00:00' day to second, interval '1 05:00:00' day to second);
```

(HourlyBlock 'Valley' begins at 23:00:00 and ends at 05:00:00 of the following day).

To test to which HourlyBlock every record in MeterData belongs, I extract the record's hour, minute and second information as an interval with the following, adding 1 day to the interval if it is less than 05:00:00 and thus belongs to HourlyBlock 'Valley':

```
    select distinct m.MeterID, m.DateHour, m.kwh,
    NUMTODSINTERVAL(m.DateHour - trunc(m.DateHour), 'DAY') + case when 
      NUMTODSINTERVAL(m.DateHour - trunc(m.DateHour), 'DAY') <= interval '00 05:00:00'
      day to second then interval '1' day else interval '0' day end as intval,
    h.HourlyBlock
    from MeterData m, HourlyBlocks h
    where (NUMTODSINTERVAL(m.DateHour - trunc(m.DateHour ), 'DAY') > h.BlockStart
    and NUMTODSINTERVAL(m.DateHour - trunc(m.DateHour ), 'DAY') + case when
      NUMTODSINTERVAL(m.DateHour - trunc(m.DateHour ), 'DAY') <= interval '00 05:00:00'
      day to second then interval '1' day else interval '0' day end <= h.BlockEnd)
```

The HourlyBlock are correctly assigned, except for records where DateHour is between 00:00:00 and 05:00:00!

What am I doing wrong?

The expected output for the sample data provided would be:

```
|MeterID|DateHour        |KWH   |intval             |HourlyBlock|
|-------|----------------|------|-------------------|-----------|
|2319927|13/06/2022 00:00|0.138 |+00 00:00:00.000000|Valley     |
|2500350|13/06/2022 00:15|0.612 |+01 00:15:00.000000|Valley     |
|2500351|13/06/2022 01:30|0.8   |+01 01:30:00.000000|Valley     |
|2500352|13/06/2022 04:00|0.288 |+01 04:00:00.000000|Valley     |
|2500353|13/06/2022 05:30|0.908 |+00 05:30:00.000000|Rest       |
|2500396|13/06/2022 12:00|68.09 |+00 12:00:00.000000|Rest       |
|2500446|13/06/2022 18:15|0     |+00 18:15:00.000000|Peak       |
|2500453|13/06/2022 21:00|2.772 |+00 21:00:00.000000|Peak       |
|2500472|13/06/2022 23:30|64.8  |+00 23:30:00.000000|Valley     |
|2500490|14/06/2022 00:30|2.4   |+01 00:30:00.000000|Valley     |
|2501352|14/06/2022 01:45|11.64 |+01 01:45:00.000000|Valley     |
|5187222|14/06/2022 06:30|1.452 |+00 06:30:00.000000|Rest       |
|5284288|14/06/2022 11:00|66.792|+00 11:00:00.000000|Rest       |
|5516997|14/06/2022 18:30|0.384 |+00 18:30:00.000000|Peak       |
```

(I'm sorry I had to format the output as code. It was the only way around that pesky "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code" error.)

Comment: Can you post the expected output for the sample data provided

Comment: Thank you. I just did.

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix, and simplified my WHERE clause:

```
    select distinct m.MeterID, m.DateHour, m.kwh,
    NUMTODSINTERVAL(m.DateHour - trunc(m.DateHour), 'DAY') + case when 
      NUMTODSINTERVAL(m.DateHour - trunc(m.DateHour), 'DAY') <= interval '00 05:00:00'
      day to second then interval '1' day else interval '0' day end as intval, h.HourlyBlock
    from MeterData m, HourlyBlocks h
    where NUMTODSINTERVAL(m.DateHour - trunc(m.DateHour), 'DAY') +
      case when NUMTODSINTERVAL(m.DateHour - trunc(m.DateHour), 'DAY')
      <= interval '00 05:00:00' day to second then interval '1' day else
      interval '0' day end between h.BlockStart + interval '1' second and h.BlockStart
```